# how to come to a decision when to use try catch block in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm automating a scenarion where login to the application, click on appropriate pages and logout.

Here how one can estimate when and where try catch needs to be used?

Comment: It's depend on your code that when you are calling any method if that method will throw an exception, you need to catch them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the situation.

1) For Cases where you want to handle the error (eg. 'FileOutputStream' will throw 'FileNotFoundException'

```
try{FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                    new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\needful\\output.xlsx"));
            workbook.write(out);
            workbook.close();
            out.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

2) Where you want your code to run even though when some function is failed. (eg. Verify and Assert)

```
Assert.assertEquals(21, 25); //here the code execution stops

//here the code fails yet the script will continue its execution.
try{
 Assert.assertEquals(21, 25);
 }catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

3) If you want to add the 'finally{}' function so that "The code inside the finally clause will always be executed, even if an exception is thrown from within the try or catch block." - [Link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html#finally)

```
public void open_File(){
        FileReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new FileReader("file\path\");
            //do something here
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //do something clever with the exception
        } finally {
            if(reader != null){
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //do something clever with the exception
                }
            }
            System.out.println("--- File Process Ended ---");
        }
    }
```